# Getting started with GSI

Tags: android

I'd like to try out [Android GSI](https://source.android.com/setup/build/gsi), and I have a few questions about it.

Where can I get the latest prebuilt images? Do I have to build it from source code myself?

How can I tell if devices I own are supported by GSI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to build GSI from source code locally:

- Android Q preview GSI ( or future preview GSI ) could be downloaded from [GSI preview site](https://developer.android.com/preview/gsi-release-notes)
- Android 9 Pie GSI could be downloaded from [GSI CI page](https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-pie-gsi/grid?)

Android devices that fully support [Treble](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture) could run GSI: devices launched with Android 9 and after are required to be fully Treble compatible. You could check your device launched OS version with:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.first_api_level
```

if it returns a value >= `28`, device could use GSI; currently installing GSI need device's bootloader unlocked, check your device's manufacturer for bootloader unlocking instructions.

Please note that GSI is for developers to perform earlier application design and validation on new Android OS; it is **NOT** suitable for normal device users: because pre-installed applications, like the phone dialer, may not function properly (could not make phone calls).